# Using a "?" when initialising an instance variable

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I am trying to have `sushiable?`  return an instance variable set in `initialise` but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
attr_accessor :weight, :value, :sushiable?

def initialize (weight,value, sushiable?)
  @weight = weight
  @value = value
  @sushiable = sushiable?
end

# def sushiable?
#   false
# end
```

Comment: Only method names may end with `?`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `?` is only valid for methods names, not for variables. So, the correct way would be:

```
attr_accessor :weight, :value, :sushiable

def initialize (weight, value, sushiable)
  @weight = weight
  @value = value
  @sushiable = sushiable
end

def sushiable?
  sushiable
end
```

Comment: am confused, why call 'sushiable' again within the method?

Comment: Actually, in this case, you don't even need the predicate `sushiable?` since the `@sushiable` variable itself  stores a test. So, calling 'object.sushiable' would be enough. However, using predicate methods is a good practice to improve readability. Do you need these attributes to be writable? If not, you could remove the redundant `sushiable` method (generated by `attr_accessor`), and rewriting the `sushiable?` method to return the `@sushiable` variable.

Comment: On a side note: what If other classes e.g (salmon, barracuda) are inheriting from this class(fish). How do I create a method that adds all the "sushiable" fishes into an array(fishBox).. e.g.

fishBox = [ ]

Comment: I don't think you need other classes, unless being a salmon changes the record's behaviour somehow. You'd actually instantiate the `Fish` class differently for each type of fish: `salmon = Fish.new(2.0, 10.0, true)` and `barracuda = Fish.new(3.0, 6.0, false)` for example. At the end, you could simply put all the instances in a pure Ruby array and use the select method: `fishes_array.select(&:sushiable?)`.

Comment: yeah that sounds like a  more reasonable option, but in this instance all those types of fishes were put in their own classes and inherited from "Fish class".

Comment: Do you mean that you're editing someone else's code? Well, even then, due to [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), you could simply put everything in the same array and apply the `select`.

Comment: Not a problem, though I'd appreciate if you choose my answer as the best answer. :)

Comment: Writing `alias sushiable? sushiable` right after the `attr_accessor` line would be simpler.

Comment: You are taking care of the reader method, but not the writer method.

Comment: The writer method is created by the `attr_accessor`. Aliasing the method is cleaner, indeed.